# Разбить список строк на массивы строк

Tags: c#, linq

У меня есть List< string>, он содержит набор строк отделённых пустой строкой, и я хочу его разбить на подмассивы основываясь на этих пустых строках.
Пример:

**List< string>:**

```
USER:    kitoung95@gmail.com
PASS:    toung778899
HOST: SMTP://123456

USER: kitoung95@gmail.com
PASS: toung778899
HOST:    SMTP://12345

USER:    kitoung95@gmail.com
PASS:    15156
HOST: SMTP://123456l/pwd
```

Я хочу получить 3 массива/списка:

**Массив 1:**

```
USER:    kitoung95@gmail.com
PASS:    toung778899
HOST: SMTP://123456
```

**Массив 2:**

```
USER: kitoung95@gmail.com
PASS: toung778899
HOST:    SMTP://12345
```

**Массив 3:**

```
USER:    kitoung95@gmail.com
PASS:    15156
HOST: SMTP://123456l/pwd
```

Как это сделать???

Comment: Какой смысл в массивах? Почему не класс/объект?

Comment: Мне нужно выделить определённые строки из списка, например HOST и PASS, если одного из них нет, то не выбирать нечего, разбив это на такие подмассивы, я могу обработать каждый. Даже если б у меня был класс, что б его наполнить правильно нужно было б разбить этот список на подмассивы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В принципе, ничего сложного. Простая функция для разделения без регулярок

```
private IEnumerable<List<string>> SplitByEmptyString(IEnumerable<string> source){
    var ret = new List<string>();
    foreach(var line in source){
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)){
            if (ret.Count > 0) yield return ret;
            ret = new List<string>();       
        }
        else ret.Add(line);
    }   
    if (ret.Count > 0) yield return ret;
}
```

Проверка

```
string str = 
@"USER:    kitoung95@gmail.com
PASS:    toung778899
HOST: SMTP://123456

USER: kitoung95@gmail.com
PASS: toung778899
HOST:    SMTP://12345

USER:    kitoung95@gmail.com
PASS:    15156
HOST: SMTP://123456l/pwd";

var lines = str.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None);

foreach(var group in SplitByEmptyString(lines))
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", group));
```

Вывод

```
USER:    kitoung95@gmail.com, PASS:    toung778899, HOST: SMTP://123456
USER: kitoung95@gmail.com, PASS: toung778899, HOST:    SMTP://12345
USER:    kitoung95@gmail.com, PASS:    15156, HOST: SMTP://123456l/pwd
```

Comment: Спасибо, кстати, благодаря ваше ответу узнал о yield return

Comment: @KuzCode на здоровье